# Checking if a list of objects contains a property

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

Hi i have a list of objects and i need to find out if the id i have is already in the list. In the object class i have set the id and i just want to find out if the one that is entered in the Ui is already in use.

The Class

```
class Product
{

    private string name = "";
    private int id = 0;
    private decimal Pvalue = 0.00m;
    private static int lastId = 1;

    public Product(string namep, decimal valuep)
    {
        this.name = namep;
        this.id = lastId++;
        this.Pvalue = valuep;
    }



    public override string ToString()
    {
        return name + "     " + id + "    "+ Pvalue;
    }


    public bool Equals(Product p)
    {

        return (p.id == this.id);
    }
}
```

Me trying to work it out:

```
 int id;

        bool test = int.TryParse(textBoxId.Text, out id);


            if(test)
            {


                if(Inv.Contains(id))
                {

                label2.Text = "you already have this id";

                }else
                {
                    label2.Text = "you can use this id";            
                }

            }
```

If any one has a idea on why this is not working or a better way it would save my back side thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change `private int id = 0;` to `public int Id { get; set; }`.  Also, change all the references from `id` to `Id`.

Add a `using System.Linq` to your business logic file.

Change `if (Inv.Contains(id))` to `if (Inv.Any(x => x.Id == id))`

Comment: Thanks for the help but im still getting the same thing "object does not contain a definition for Id"

Comment: I assumed `Inv` referred to a collection of some sort containing Product instances.  It needs to be for the above code to work:  IEnumerable<Product> Inv = ...